# Scalable multi threaded String object in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, string, scalability

I'm doing a little research for a server application I'm planning to build. 
The main function will be - lots of users will be able to perform live editing.

So looking into all the options for a scalable string, which basically be some kind of stringbuffer but be able to handle lots(hundreds?) of threads working on it at the same time with quite a large amount of text.

Instead of reinventing the wheel, I hope to see libraries shared that have such features :)
I couldn't really find much with Google.

Comment: Is a string really the correct data structure for your document? Is it entirely plain text? And even if it is, how do you address specific parts inside the text? In the face of concurrent modification of some text saying "character 200 up to character 210" is *not* a reliable way to address some string.

Comment: you could also consider an optimistic approach - ie are 100 people really going to edit at the same time. Maybe but some wikis work on a "detect a clash and merge" approach and see most edits go uncontested... ?

Comment: Basically, the problem is as Joachim implies -- the "string" is not the right physical structure, even though the document may be viewed as a string conceptually.  If one person is editing page 2 and another editing page 4, a simple StringBuffer isn't going to hack it.  As I said in my answer, you really need some sort of database, and then a protocol on top to remember how the pieces fit together (and to allow sections to be cut/pasted, etc).  It' a challenging task.

Comment: "Is a string really the correct data structure for your document?" Well underneath I don't really care. The rope string data structure looks good. It is entirely plain text.
"ie are 100 people really going to edit at the same time."
Yeah they could. Though maybe I could allow sections and have a max amount of people edit a certain section.
Maybe I don't really need multi-threaded. Each section can have its own scalable string object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was keep track of changes since you no longer rely on the index, it made things difficult.

So I'm currently looking at storing the strings in something like a LinkHashMap or ListOrderedMap now. But still doing more research in the correct data structure ...

Edit: At this stage I will go with a ListOrderedMap to store my strings in and see how that goes...

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the sourcecode of [Etherpad](http://etherpad.org/) - it's a Java-based collaborative text editing web app, so it has to have some sort of string implementation that allows concurrent write access to separate regions of the string, presumably without losing data. Of course, whether it fulfills your performance requirements is a different matter...

Comment: Ah very similar in what I'm looking to build heh. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

**String itself is thread-safe** (since it is immutable) and fairly high-performance for most use cases.

The main performance issue with String is that in O(n) in the length of the string for mutations (due to the need to take a complete copy).

If you need to deal with very long strings you probably want to use a [Rope data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29). There are several implementations available in Java:

- [Ropes for Java](http://ahmadsoft.org/ropes/) - seems a very good implementation
- [My own implementation](http://code.google.com/p/mikeralib/source/browse/trunk/Mikera/src/main/java/mikera/persistent/Text.java) - which is less general but might be faster for the implemented operations as it is designed for very low overhead.

Both of the Rope implementations above conform to the **CharSequence** interface (which String also implements), so if you design your application to work with CharSequences instead of Strings then you can start with Strings and switch to Ropes later if you decide you need them.

Comment: Thanks, will now go research into it :)

Answer (score 1):

[This talk](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/4902-woot-for-scala-javascript-and-lift) (free reg. required) describes the kinds of algorithms used by the likes of Google Docs etc for multi-user editing, and demonstrates a simple implementation. In Scala but applicable to any language.

Edit: oops, a bit late! Might be useful to someone anyway...

Comment: I never actually started on the application and still on my list of things to write. I'll give it a watch :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, [StringBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) is thread-safe. You could base your system on that.

Comment: As a start yes. But it only allows one thread to work on it at the same time iirc.

Comment: No you are mistaken - StringBuffer allows **many** threads to operate on it **at the same time** - that is the definition of "thread-safe". Please follow link and read the javadoc there

Comment: I have read the javadoc. Thread-safe means, safe for use by multiple threads(as quoted in the javadoc). Does not mean it allows multiple threads to do the work at the same time. Unless I somehow missed that in the javadoc, then feel free to point that out :)

Comment: Multiple threads can modify the same StringBuffer.  They have to acquire the lock first.  I guess if you do a `insert(offset, string)`, but an other thread has inserted some text before the `offset`, then you won't insert in the right position (the javadoc is unclear and I have not tested it).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it would be a challenge.  You need to allow individual users to "lock" the parts of the string they're working on, while others can lock and work on other parts.  So basically what you're talking about is a form of database.

You could probably do it with SQL, but you'd have to invent a protocol.